# tensorflow einsum gets the trace wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Why are these outputs different? Is this intended behavior? I'm using tensorflow 1.12

```
import tensorflow as tf

matrix = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                      [4, 5, 6],
                      [7, 8, 9]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.einsum('ii',matrix).eval())

# 45
```

while

```
import numpy as np

np.einsum('ii',[[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]])
# 15 (as it should be)
```

Why is tensorflow's einsum summing all the elements of the matrix?

UPDATE: I've opened an issue on GitHub, it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed and merged in PR 25079.